# MSBUILD LESS targets file that copies css on publish

Tags: msbuild, less

http://pastebin.com/C0K4B7eK

I created this targets file to perform the following actions:

- On Build, compile .less files marked with build action "LESSCompile" using different settings for Debug and Release...WORKS!!!
- On Clean, remove compiled .css and .css.map files, ones compiled from .less files with build action "LESSCompile"...WORKS!!!
- On Publish/Deploy, copy generated .css (and .css.map files if Debug) to publish directory in the same location as the original .less file (marked with build action "LESSCompile")...NO WORK :-(

The .css file copies but not the .css.map.  I'm very, very, very, new to writing MSBUILD scripts, but from my limited knowledge, it seems correct.

Any assistance would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!!

Comment: This was my final solution: http://pastebin.com/6PQuqBFn.  Way cleaner. Setting the generated files to content was the way to go.